# "typescript unexpected token import" on GDAX-tt - tried to follow other fixes for other software to no avail

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsconfig, gdax-api, unexpected-token

Obviously, if you search "typescript unexpected token import" you get zillions of results. They are all about some specific problem, not about how to tackle the problem in general. So, I am having problem learning from other answers to fix my issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using:

Mac OS X

npm v5.5.1

yarn v1.3.2

ts-node v4.1.0

node v9.2.1

typescript v2.6.2

I am following this: https://coinbase.github.io/gdax-tt/gtt_installation.html

I installed yarn.

I updated npm.

I used yarn to add gdax-tt.

I used npm to install typescript.

I am using the recommended tsconfig.json. It is listed as this on the install page:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "module": "commonjs",
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": ["es6", "es2016", "ES2016.Array.Include", "dom", "ES2017.object"],
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "strictNullChecks": false,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "outDir": "build",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "allowJs": true
 },
  "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
 ]
}
```

But is on the github as:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
 "module": "commonjs",
 "target": "es6",
 "lib": ["es6", "es2016", "ES2016.Array.Include", "dom", "ES2017.object"],
 "noImplicitAny": true,
 "noImplicitReturns": true,
 "noImplicitThis": true,
 "noUnusedLocals": true,
 "strictNullChecks": false,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "outDir": "build",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "declaration": true,
 "skipLibCheck": true
},
"include": [
  "types/*.d.ts",
  "src/**/*.ts",
  "test/**/*.ts"
 ],
 "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
 ]
}
```

I've tried both, but since I am new to TS, I am not sure I have used them correctly. How would I check?

I can get the following to run:

```
ts-node ./build/src/consoles/gdaxConsole.js --product BTC-USD -t
```

But when I run

```
ts-node ./tutorials/t001_feeds.ts
```

I get this:

```
import * as GTT from 'gdax-trading-toolkit';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:605:28)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:414:14)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:682:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/_bin.ts:177:12)
```

I see a lot of solutions on this site and others for the "unexpected token import", but all of them seem to be fairly specific advice that I cannot translate into a solution for me.

Can someone point me to a resource for understanding/debugging this error or help me solve this specific case?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have already solved your problem. In the event that you have not, I have gotten this to run on my Mac. Mine has the github version (the one with the "include") in the gdax-tt directory. So I don't think that is the problem.
One thing I notice is that the js (javascript) is running fine but the ts appears to not be working. Have you run anything else with ts-node? have you tried "which ts-node" to make sure it is pointing correctly?

I wish I had more for you but I'm not getting anything to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that if the gdax-tt code is in a node_modules directory than it isn't compiled so one needs to pass the `--no-ignore` flag to ts-node.

I found the hint [here](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/505) which led to `ts-node`'s [command line arguments](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#configuration-options) which says:

--ignore Specify an array of regular expression strings for ts-node
to skip compiling as TypeScript (defaults to `/node_modules`/,
`--no-ignore/false` to disable)